# Shutdown NiFi on Windows

Tags: windows, shutdown, apache-nifi

Is there an easy programmatic way to shutdown NiFi on windows? The "manual" way works, run in a command window and press ctr-c to quit, but I'm trying to automate a testing environment. I can use the nifi.sh script on linux and I've seen reference to a shutdown bat script when googling but I'm using 0.6.1 and it isn't in that version.

I've used netstat to find the PID based on the API Port number and then killed that process. But it appears there are always two processes and one will restart the other. So I did the same thing, with the Bootstrap port, used it to find the PID of the process and then killed that process as well. But this hasn't always been reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NiFi does support running on Windows but does not currently support tying into the Windows Service Management.  Doable for sure and if you're interested helping contribute either via mailing list, JIRA entry and discussion or code commits the community would be happy to collaborate

Answer (score 9):

You can stop nifi on windows. To do that you have to open **run-nifi.bat** file and replace **run** to stop in the file.

Then save as the file as **nifi-stop.bat**

So the content of **nifi-stop.bat** will looks like this.

```
@echo off
rem
rem    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
rem    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
rem    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
rem    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
rem    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
rem    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
rem
rem       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
rem
rem    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
rem    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
rem    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
rem    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
rem    limitations under the License.
rem

rem Set environment variables

call %~sdp0\nifi-env.bat

rem Use JAVA_HOME if it's set; otherwise, just use java

if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" goto noJavaHome
if not exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto noJavaHome
set JAVA_EXE=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe
goto startNifi

:noJavaHome
echo The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
echo Instead the PATH will be used to find the java executable.
echo.
set JAVA_EXE=java
goto startNifi

:startNifi
pushd "%NIFI_ROOT%"
set LIB_DIR=lib\bootstrap
set CONF_DIR=conf

set BOOTSTRAP_CONF_FILE=%CONF_DIR%\bootstrap.conf
set JAVA_ARGS=-Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.log.dir=%NIFI_LOG_DIR% -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.pid.dir=%NIFI_PID_DIR% -Dorg.apache.nifi.bootstrap.config.file=%BOOTSTRAP_CONF_FILE%

SET JAVA_PARAMS=-cp %CONF_DIR%;%LIB_DIR%\* -Xms12m -Xmx24m %JAVA_ARGS% org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi
set BOOTSTRAP_ACTION=stop

cmd.exe /C "%JAVA_EXE%" %JAVA_PARAMS% %BOOTSTRAP_ACTION%

popd
```

Now you can stop nifi just running this file nifi-stop.bat.

Answer (score 0):

I checked around, and it looks like there's no official support for Windows. Not familiar with exact issues the team encountered with shutdown there, though. Maybe there's an easier way to stand up NiFi for testing? E.g. is it some integration testing you're doing that requires a full instance up?

Regarding 2 processes. You need to kill bootstrap first, otherwise there's a chance it will detect the main process down and restart it (depends on timing of your tests).

Comment: Yes, it's for a system/integration tests. All our build machines are currently on windows so I was updating my SBT config to automate starting/shutting down NiFi. At some point we'll move everything into Docker containers so I assume I can just call the Linux shell commands then (or just shut down the container).

Answer (score -1):

If you like you can use this dockerized container of NiFi which should run on docker on windows 
[Apache NiFi on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/santanu77/apache-nifi/)